# Customizing fonts on desktop icons

Tags: gnome, themes, fonts

I was wondering how one changes the fonts for desktop icons in Ubuntu 18.04. I have the Macbuntu-O theme running as well.

Do I modify the theme's gnome-shell.css file or the gtk.css file? I have studied the gnome-shell.css file but haven't found something that catches my eye yet. But, in the gtk.css file I found this:

```
.nautilus-desktop.nautilus-canvas-item, .nemo-desktop.nemo-canvas-item, .caja-desktop {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); }
  .nautilus-desktop.nautilus-canvas-item:active, .nemo-desktop.nemo-canvas-item:active, .caja-desktop:active {
    color: #252525; }
  .nautilus-desktop.nautilus-canvas-item:selected, .nemo-desktop.nemo-canvas-item:selected, .caja-desktop:selected {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: none; }
```

Could I modify the code by placing a line such as "font-weight: bold;" below color for example?

I noticed the fonts change when you apply the relevant shell-theme (e.g. Macbuntu-O) in the Tweaks tool. That makes me think it is somehow linked to the gnome-shell.css file as well, or am I missing something?

Comment: See https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/07/finally-change-gnome-shell-font-interface

Comment: Thanks @DK Bose. I'm having trouble understanding the video though.

Comment: Just to update, I edited the gtk.css file in the gtk-3.0 folder, and played with the settings of the shadow as well as added the font-weight: bold part to the code above. What I get is the shadow changing, but the font stays normal (no effect/change).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the input everyone -- is actually quite simple just using the dconf editor, as was used in the link posted by @Mogli.

In org/gnome/nautilus/desktop/font, one moves the slider that says "use default value" to the off position, then type in "sans bold" at the custom value:

[image]

As one can see, the text below the icons goes bold immediately:

[image]

Edit: with time I have found that one should actually use just "bold" at Custom Value, as this ensures the font you use in the gnome-shell.css file is definitely used on the desktop. I found this out upon changing the font to something else, and noticed that the font on the desktop did not change with it when using the "sans bold" value.